# Is is possible to use AWS Storage Gateway as an iSCSI target for ESXi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vmware-esxi, iscsi

#### Summary

Is is possible to use AWS Storage Gateway as an iSCSI target for ESXi?

-- or --

AWS Storage Gateway volumes not showing up in ESXi iSCSI device list - what's up with that?

**TLDR:** Based on [this VMWare forum post](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/399460), it sounds like it's not possible to use an AWS Storage Gateway volume as an iSCSI target for VMWare ESXi. **Can anyone tell me otherwise?**

#### Background

I'm playing with AWS Storage Gateway (SG). My end goal is to add a datastore to my VMWare ESXi 5.5 cluster and migrate some VMs to this AWS volume.

I've created the storage gateway appliance (192.168.75.60 set via DHCP reservation) on my ESXi cluster and given it a couple drives for upload buffer and local cache. Using a Proxmox hypervisor on a separate test server, I have verified that I can access the SG iSCSI volumes - I've created multiple dummy VMs using the SG iSCSI successfully.

#### Steps Taken

However, now I'm trying to test things out with VMWare ESXi 5.5 and am having trouble adding the iSCSI devices.

Basically I've been following the instructions found [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.solutions.doc/GUID-17FAA11E-E4F7-4C55-99DC-E0A24B1ABDD6.html), but it ends up not working. Steps Taken:

1. Added a VMKernel standard network switch (using a physical adapter that is not connected). Static IP address 192.168.75.61.
2. Added the VMKernel port binding to for the switch created in (1) to the the iSCSI Software Adapter
3. Added the SG address to iSCSI Dynamic Discovery. Dynamic Discovery successfully finds my AWS SG volumes and populates the Static Discovery list.

At this point, I rescan the iSCSI adapter, but the volumes do not show up on the Devices or Paths lists :-(.

Thus far my google-fu is failing. All I'm able to find is information relating to installing the AWS SG virtual appliance on ESXi and [this AWS forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=238913) and [this VMWare forum post](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/399460) that sounds similar to the trouble I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Yes it's possible.

**Long(er) Answer:**

You (I) did one critical thing wrong:

> using a physical adapter that is not connected

If you plug in that adapter to your switch and make sure that it's on the same subnet/VLAN as your storage gateway VM, then you should be able to connect.

Why the same subnet/VLAN? Based on the post you linked, it says that ESXi does not support iSCSI routing. All that means is you need to have the SG on the same subnet/lan as whatever your switch port is. Since the SG is a VM on the hypervisor, it's likely part of the VM Port Group for your VM Network.

**Note:** If you're running a cluster, you'll have to add the physical connection and the vSwitches + iSCSI dynamic discovery stuff to all hosts in the cluster.

[image]